# android how to get unsigned byte array from getinputstream

Tags: android, arrays, inputstream

I use `getInputStream` from `socket`; however, when I want to convert my byte array to long it will get the wrong number. When I used debug mode to see each value of the byte array, I found the value would be signed. How can I convert my signed byte array to unsigned array? Or I got the wrong sense that the problem was not related to the `signed` problem. If there's any information insufficient, please tell me. Thanks.

Below is my code:

```
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

byte[] fileNameBytes = new byte[8];
byte[] totalLengthBytes = new byte[8];
try {
    inputStream.read(fileNameBytes);
    inputStream.read(totalLengthBytes);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("Error in InputStream: " + ex.getMessage());
}

totalLength = byteArrayToLong(totalLengthBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

java has issues with signed/unsigned. Namely, no unsigned.  When I've need to upload raw bytes to a C# web service that expects bytes to be unsigned (ie 0 to 255 vs -127 to +127), I've used code I'm not proud of, that looks like:

```
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (bytearray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytearray.length; ++i) 
            {
                l.add(Integer.valueOf((char) bytearray [i]) & 0x00FF);
            }
        }
```

Where `bytearray` is a `byte[]`